# Add Column when using rowFormatter (Cheese Example)

Tags: tabulator

I feel I am missing something simple... The cheese example of how to use the rowFormatter is exactly how I want to implement something, except I'd like to add various additional columns...

I've noted the warning `it is important to include only one column in your column definition array to ensure the table renders correctly`, however it is exactly what I want to do.

So I tried adding another column to the table constructor which added a column heading but no data.

What an I missing? Surely this is a common use case?

Comment: @Uwe Keim, I'm new here... Can you please explain why being polite and thanking people with potential answers needs to be edited and downvoted?

Comment: Because it [creates unnecessary noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/133056). Please [don't include "Thank you" in your questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/133056).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `formatter` option as apposed to the `rowFormatter` - which overwrites the entire rows contents.

Based on the printIcon and cheese examples in the [Tabulator docs](http://tabulator.info/examples/3.4?#formatters), construct a column formatter, but pass the row as apposed to the cell.

Then its just a matter of constructing the html table as per the cheese example, but return the table, don't append to the element.

My Test Example:

```
//Generate details
    var details = function(row, formatterParams){ //plain text value

        var element = row.getElement(),
        data = row.getData(),
        width = element.outerWidth(),
        table;

        //define a table layout structure and set width of row
        table = $("<table style='width:" + (width - 18) + "px;'><tr></tr></table>");

        //add image on left of row
        $("tr", table).append("<td><img src='./img/teams/small-60x80/55015.png'></td>");

        //add row data on right hand side
        $("tr", table).append("<td><div><strong>Type:</strong> " + data.type + "</div><div><strong>Age:</strong> " + data.age + "</div><div><strong>Rind:</strong> " + data.rind + "</div><div><strong>Colour:</strong> " + data.color + "</div></td>");

        //append newly formatted contents to the row
        //element.append(table);
        return table;

        //return "<image src='./img/teams/small-60x80/55015.png'>";
    };

    //define Tabulator
    $("#example-table").tabulator({
        height:"600px",
        layout:"fitColumns",
        resizableColumns:false,
        columns:[
            {formatter:details},
            {title:"Cheese", field:"type", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Something Else", field:"blah", sorter:"string"},
        ],

    })
```